# Time to Live(ttl) value in IP DATAGRAM computer networks

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing, ping

I have a query regarding TTL in computer networks

according to JAMES F. KUROSE in the book COMPUTER NETWORKING-a top-down approach

```
Time -to-live- The time-to-live (TTL) field is included to ensure that datagrams 
do not circulate forever (for example, a long-lived routing loop) in the network.
This field is decremented by one each time the datagram is processed by a router. 
If the TTL field reaches 0, a router must drop that datagram.
```

My question is whether **TTL becomes 0 or not when the packet reaches the destination** host or it will have some value remaining in it?

I noticed from the ping command in UBUNTU that the ping command has TTL=64 even if the destination is the same device(pinging loopback), if so the TTL won't be reduced to 0 on reaching the destination
and windows has a TTL set to 128.

**my question is**

1)So does TTL vary for every IP packet made depending on destination? or is it predefined by the OS for every packet?

2)Is it zero when it reaches the destination host to which the packet was intended to be sent?if no, how does TTL help in recognising the destination host machine

Comment: TTL is decremented when the packet is sent, so the last router will accept the TTL=0 packet, and then drop it rather than forwarding it on. unless of course the router is the target of the IP datagram.

Comment: its my understanding that most OS's default to 64 for all or most connections. it doesn't vary widely based on dynamic characteristics. TTL should be >0 upon arrival. if it is 0, you just squeaked by, but really the value is supposed to give you more than enough headroom to arrive at the destination. TTL doesn't help in recognizing the destination machine. it is designed to limit the damage that could occur if part of the internetwork was misconfigured to cause loops. instead of looping forever it would stop safely, rather than saturating the looped networks.